# Booting Ubuntu 13.10 from USB on server with no OS (Dell PowerEdge T110)

Tags: boot, 13.10, dell, bios, unetbootin

I have a Dell PowerEdge T110 (Xeon 1220v2) server with no OS. From my mac, I was able to save the Ubuntu 13.10 for server iso (x86) and used UNetbootin to save the iso to a USB stick (2GB).

I was hoping to boot the server from USB, and all seemed to be going well, BIOS even detected my USB drive when I plugged it in, but for some reason I'm getting a "Missing operating system" error. I checked the USB drive and it appears that UNetbootin put the correct files on it form a cursory glance (although I'm not entirely sure what I should be looking for).

Should I be able to boot a server with no OS from a UNetbootin created Ubuntu 13.10 USB? And if so, why might BIOS not find the right files?

I had read that there is a USB Emulation setting in BIOS, but I haven't been able to find this in the menus. My understanding is that by default, this is set to on.

I might try wiping the USB stick and running UNetbootin again. The USB is formatted to MS-DOS FAT16 (should it be formatted some other way?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I believe that this USB stick was not "bootable"

To give everyone some more background, this was a corporate give away usb stick. Even when I pointed the BIOS to the external usb drive, it failed to load.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should format your USB stick by FAT32.

Maybe [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) will helping you.

Comment: I will try that. In theory I think it should work with either FAT16 or FAT32, but FAT32 makes more sense.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.